# How do I find out the last time DBCC Checkstorage was run on Sybase ASE?

Tags: logging, sap-ase, dbcc

I'm working with my DBAs and asking them to execute a number of steps in sequence.

What command do I run to out the last time DBCC Checkstorage was run on Sybase ASE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think sp_dbcc_summaryreport should be close enough.